# React Native: Is there a way to add an event listener to elements through ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In React for the web we can use the DOM API like this:

```
ref.addEventListener('click', () => {})
```

In React native though, I couldn't find a similar API.
Currently the only way I know to attach listeners to components is to stitch them directly in the JSX, like this:

```
<View
  onTouchStart={() => {}}
  ... />
```

Which is fine. But in my case I want to listen to an event *only* when another listener has fired. So I want something like this:

```
ref.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
  ref.addEventListener('touchmove', () => {
    /* ... */
  })
})
```